# Copy specifc key-value pair from one dictionary into another?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to take a key-value pair from the following dictionary

```
inventory = {0:["Boots",34],
                1:["T-shirt",12],
                2:["Jeans", 25],
                3:["Socks", 4]
                }
```

and copy that specific key-value pair into an empty dictionary

```
cart = {}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
cart.append(inventory[i])
```

i being the key value pair index you are trying to append.